# compiling a minecraft mod error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I have been trying to compile a Minecraft mod using Eclipse and Forge but I just get errors
I think it is something to do with linking the Minecraft libraries but am not sure
here is my code

```
package com.example.examplemod;

import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler;
import cpw.mods.fml.common.event.FMLInitializationEvent;

@Mod(modid = ExampleMod.MODID, version = ExampleMod.VERSION)
public class ExampleMod
{
    public static final String MODID = "examplemod";
    public static final String VERSION = "1.0";

    @EventHandler
    public void init(FMLInitializationEvent event)
    {
        Block amethystOre = new ModBlock(Material.rock, "amethystOre");
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(amethystOre, "amethystOre");
    }
    private class ModBlock extends Block
    {
        public ModBlock(Material material, String blockName)
        {
            super(material);
            this.setBlockName(blockName);
            this.setBlockTextureName(MODID + ":" + blockName);
            this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
        }
    }
}
```

I was following a guide and  I am supposed to get a "BUILD SUCCSEFUL" message at the end
the guide is https://blog.usejournal.com/a-beginners-guide-to-modding-minecraft-9a42536495f6

Here's the error

```
#################################################
         ForgeGradle 1.2-SNAPSHOT-fb514d3
  https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle
#################################################
               Powered by MCP unknown
             http://modcoderpack.com
         by: Searge, ProfMobius, Fesh0r,
         R4wk, ZeuX, IngisKahn, bspkrs
#################################################
:compileApiJava UP-TO-DATE
:processApiResources UP-TO-DATE
:apiClasses UP-TO-DATE
:sourceMainJava UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
C:\Minecraft Workspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    private class ModBlock extends Block
                                   ^
  symbol:   class Block
  location: class ExampleMod
C:\Minecraft Workspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        public ModBlock(Material material, String blockName)
                        ^
  symbol:   class Material
  location: class ExampleMod.ModBlock
C:\Minecraft Workspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        Block amethystOre = new ModBlock(Material.rock, "amethystOre");
        ^
  symbol:   class Block
  location: class ExampleMod
C:\Minecraft Workspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
        Block amethystOre = new ModBlock(Material.rock, "amethystOre");
                                         ^
  symbol:   variable Material
  location: class ExampleMod
C:\Minecraft Workspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
        GameRegistry.registerBlock(amethystOre, "amethystOre");
        ^
  symbol:   variable GameRegistry
  location: class ExampleMod
C:\Minecraft Workspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
            this.setBlockName(blockName);
                ^
  symbol: method setBlockName(String)
C:\Minecraft Workspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
            this.setBlockTextureName(MODID + ":" + blockName);
                ^
  symbol: method setBlockTextureName(String)
C:\Minecraft Workspace\forge-1.7.10-10.13.4.1558-1.7.10-src\build\sources\java\com\example\examplemod\ExampleMod.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
            this.setCreativeTab(CreativeTabs.tabBlock);
                                ^
  symbol:   variable CreativeTabs
  location: class ExampleMod.ModBlock
8 errors
1 warning
:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Have you imported everything correctly?

Comment: This is using quite an old version of Forge, is there a particular reason you are pressed to work with an old version like that?

Comment: I will try a new version

Comment: How are you compiling? You **must** use `gradlew build` in the command line, Eclipse cannot do it.

Comment: Yes I am using powershell on the forge folder

Answer (score 1):

You might try `import net.minecraft.block.Block;` instead of `import net.minecraft.init.Blocks;`.